# what does this error mean in android studio?, how to solve this issue?

Tags: android-studio

> Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid.

I cannot find the java executable. I tried location:

> C:\Users\Abhi Pattar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\bin\java.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the space in "Abhi Pattar". You will often run into errors if you have spaces in your pathname. Try renaming that folder to "AbhiPattar" or "Abhi_Pattar".